# Fullscreen mode prevent the screen saver?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I use the following code to enable FullScreen mode:

```
void CMainFrame::OnViewFullscreen()
{
    EnableFullScreenMode(0);
    ShowFullScreen();
}
```

What I have discovered is that when the program runs in FullScreen mode, the screen saver seems to be never be called.

Further, all of my keyboard shortcut keys, ex: <kbd>CTRL+ALT+C</kbd> for `calc.exe`, don't work in FullScreen mode, either.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Show `EnableFullScreenMode`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It's a library method, part of `CFrameWndEx` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982637.aspx